# How to upgrade rocksdb used by substrate node template?

Tags: rocks-db

In my parachain that I forked from substrate-node-template, github dependabot give me following security alert:

"rocksdb vulnerable to out-of-bounds read"

and the suggested solution is to upgrate rocksdb to 0.19.0. So how can I upgrade rocksdb to 0.19.0 t to fix this security alert?

Answer (score 2):

1. `rocksdb` is required by `kv-rocksdb`
2. `kv-rocksdb` is required by `sc-client-db`
3. `sc-client-db` is a Substrate workspace member/crate

---

To fix this:

- update your Substrate version

or

- fork Substrate version that you are using now, and modify the `sc-client-db` yourself

or

You can try `cargo update`, but I think that won't help too much. Most of the time, Substrate sticks/locks on a specific rocksdb version.

Comment: My current sc-client-db version is 0.10.0-dev, so should I up grade it to some other version?  here is the details of my cargo.lock

 [[package]]
name = "sc-client-db"
version = "0.10.0-dev"

Comment: You should take a look into the `sc-client-db`'s `Cargo.toml` to figure that out.